# cakephp Views and layout

Tags: php, cakephp, footer

I designed a footer in the default.ctp layout

```
 <div class="container-fluid footer-wrapper hidden-xs hidden-sm " style="margin-top:50px;">
     <div class = "row" style="padding-top:50px;">
        <div class="col-md-4">
some text 
</div></div></div>
```

and so 
and now I have a another file purchase.ctp , so just writing
`<?php echo $this->Element('footer'); ?>` , will it implement the footer from default.ctp to purchases.ctp  or do i have to make some changes to the default.ctp footer or write some code there?

I am new to cakePHP , so might sound like a foolish question.

Comment: purchases.ctp is different layout or it's only view file?

Comment: [RTM](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html). You need to understand the key concepts of layouts, views, elements.

Comment: @Salines different layout

Comment: You want to have your include statement in the default.ctp. Your footer needs to be a separate .ctp file if you want it to be uniform throughout.

Comment: Create footer.ctp in Elements folder and include in both layouts with ```<?php echo $this->element('footer'); ?>```

Comment: @Salines while creating the footer.ctp should i add the css and js or should i just write the code for the footer ?

Comment: Just write html / php code for footer

Comment: @Salines so right now the footer show up , but for some reason the footer of the default.ctp shows up as well so i have like two footers now.

Comment: Remove footer code from default.ctp, only leave this php code that calls footer.ctp element

Comment: add in default.ctp `<?php echo $this->Element('footer'); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

When creating a footer like that, it should not be in your `default.ctp` layout.

In order to re-use the footer on multiple layouts, create a new element:

- `app/View/Elements/footer.ctp` file (when using CakePHP 2.x)
- *or* `src/Template/Element/footer.ctp` file (when using CakePHP 3.x).

Then in both your `default.ctp` layout and your `purchases.ctp` layout, simply embed it:

```
echo $this->element('footer');
```

That way, whenever you edit anything in your footer, it will edit in all the layouts that use it.

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE I GOT IT FINALLY :D